# Problemas para editar datos de tabla HTML con Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

este es mi js:

```
var ubic_au_beca= 0;
var bool_au_beca= true;
//AGREGAR A TABLA LOS INPUTS !!!!!!!!!
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nombre = "";
  var apellido = "";
  var vinculo = "";
  var fechanacimiento = "";
  var telcel = "";
  var ocupacion ="";
  var ingreso = "";
  var comentarioingreso = "";
  var ttarea2 = "";
  var ttarea3 ="";
  var ttarea4 = "";
  var ttarea5 = "";

  $('#btn-agregar-a-tabla').click(function() {
    var form = $( "#form" );
    form.validate();
    //Validaciones de campos
    if (form.valid())
    {
      //para no poner mas de 5 elementos en la tabla.
      if($("#datosentabla tr").length <= 5 && bool_au_beca)
      {
        //obtenemos el valor de los input
        nombre = document.getElementById("nombref").value;
        apellido = document.getElementById("apellidof").value;
        vinculo = document.getElementById("vinculo").value;
        fechanacimiento = document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value;
        telcel = document.getElementById("telcel").value;
        ocupacion = document.getElementById("ocupacion").value;
        ingreso = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
        comentarioingreso = document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value;
        ttarea2 = document.getElementById("ttarea2").value;
        ttarea3 = document.getElementById("ttarea3").value;
        ttarea4 = document.getElementById("ttarea4").value;
        ttarea5 = document.getElementById("ttarea5").value;
        //validamos que esten con datos....

        var i = 1; //contador para asignar id al boton que borrara la fila
        var fila = '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input name="nombret[]" value="'+nombre+'"></td><td><input name="apellidot[]" value="'+apellido+'"></td><td><button type="button" name="upd_igf" id="upd_'+i+'" class="btn btn-success btn_upd">Editar</button> <button type="button" name="remove" id="del_'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="vinculot[]" value="'+vinculo+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="fechanacimientot[]" value="'+fechanacimiento+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="telcelt[]" value="'+telcel+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ocupaciont[] value="'+ocupacion+'""></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ingresoestimadot[]" value="'+ingreso+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="comentarioingresot[]" value="'+comentarioingreso+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea2t[]" value="'+ttarea2+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea3t[]" value="'+ttarea3+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea4t[]" value="'+ttarea4+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea5t[]" value="'+ttarea5+'"></td></tr>';

       //esto seria lo que contendria la fila

        i++;

        $('#datosentabla tr:last').after(fila);
        $("#adicionados").text("");

        var nFilas = $("#datosentabla tr").length;
        $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
      }
      else if ($("#datosentabla tr").length <= 5 && !bool_au_beca)
      {
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='nombret[]']").val(document.getElementById("nombref").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='apellidot[]']").val(document.getElementById("apellidof").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='vinculot[]']").val(document.getElementById("vinculo").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='fechanacimientot[]']").val(document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='telcelt[]']").val(document.getElementById("telcel").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='ocupaciont[]']").val(document.getElementById("ocupacion").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='ingresoestimadot[]']").val(document.getElementById("ingreso").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='comentarioingresot[]']").val(document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='ttarea2t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea2").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='ttarea3t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea3").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='ttarea4t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea4").value);
        $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+($("#datosentabla tr").length-1)).find("input[name='ttarea5t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea5").value);

        bool_au_beca= true;
      }
      else
      {
       alert('No se puede agregar mas familiares, número de familiares maximo');
      }

      document.getElementById("apellidof").value ="";
      document.getElementById("nombref").value = "";
      //document.getElementById("nombref").focus();
      document.getElementById("vinculo").value = "";
      document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value = "";
      document.getElementById("telcel").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ocupacion").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ingreso").value = "";
      document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea2").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea3").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea4").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea5").value = "";
      document.getElementById("observaciones").value = "";
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Corriga los campos antes de agregar a la tabla');
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");

    //cuando da click obtenemos el id del boton
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove(); //borra la fila
    //limpia el para que vuelva a contar las filas de la tabla
    $("#adicionados").text("");

    var nFilas = $("#datosentabla tr").length;
    $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
  });

  function upd_igf()
  {

  }

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_upd', function() {
    //
    ubic_au_beca= $(this).attr("id").replace("upd_","");
    bool_au_beca= false;

    document.getElementById("nombref").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='nombret[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("apellidof").value=       $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='apellidot[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("vinculo").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='vinculot[]']").val()
    document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value= $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='fechanacimientot[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("telcel").value=          $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='telcelt[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("ocupacion").value=       $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='ingresoestimadot[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("ingreso").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='ingresoestimadot[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value= $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='comentarioingresot[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("ttarea2").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='ttarea2t[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("ttarea3").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='ttarea3t[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("ttarea4").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='ttarea4t[]']").val();
    document.getElementById("ttarea5").value=         $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='ttarea5t[]']").val();
  });
});
```

Pero no se edita de forma correcta, el problema es que cuando presiono en el boton guardar no se guardan correctamente en la tabla los datos.

EDIT:  El problema esta en la variable i. Esta asignando mal las asignaciones para cada ROW. Como lo puedo solucioanr????

Comment: No te sería mas sencillo usar un array en vez que usar "$("#datosentabla tr").length"?asi tendrías mas control y evitas un poco mas los errores

Comment: Como seria Josue ?